# OpenMPI: Multiple Ethernet Interfaces Failure

Tags: mpi, openmpi, hpc

I wanted to setup a 3-node ring network, each connects to the other 2 using 2 Ethernet ports directly without a switch/router.

The interface configurations looks like this:
[image: mpi-config]

I've used *ifconfig* on each node to configure each port, and made sure I can ssh from each node to the other 2 nodes.

But a simple [ring_c](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/master/examples/ring_c.c) example doesn't work... So I turn on  --mca btl_base_verbose 30, I could see that **node1 was trying to use 23.0.0.2  (linke between node2 and 3) to get to node2** though there is a direct link to node 2.

The output log is like:

> [node1:01828] btl: tcp: attempting to connect() to [[19529,1],1]
>   address 23.0.0.2 on port 1024
>   [[19529,1],0][btl_tcp_endpoint.c:606:mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_start_connect]
>   from node1 to: node2 Unable to connect to the peer 23.0.0.2  on port
>   4: Network is unreachable

I've read the following posts and FAQs but still couldn't understand this kind of behavior.

[How does Open MPI know which IP addresses are routable to each other in Open MPI 1.3 (and beyond)?](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tcp#tcp-routability-1.3)

[How do I tell Open MPI which IP interfaces / networks to use?](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tcp#tcp-selection)

[Open MPI User's Mailing List Archives](http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2014/11/25810.php)

Any pointers would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

My open-mpi info:

Open MPI: 1.0.0.22

Open RTE: 1.0.0.22

OPAL: 1.0.0.22

MPI API: 2.1

Best,
Shang